# How can I add a PWA to the home screen without the mini Chrome logo showing?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have been testing basic PWA features with a brand new create-react-app application.  This has been going well, but when I use an emulated Android device and add the application to the home screen through Chrome, there is always a mini Chrome logo showing on the bottom right of the app.

I have run audits through lighthouse and everything seems to check out.

```
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "144x144 64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "sample.png",
      "sizes": "500x500",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I am just trying to figure out the current requirements to allow add to home screen to not include the chrome logo on the app icon.  If more context/information is needed feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the issue may be caused because of the need for the url to be https.  I was thinking in terms of localhost being ok for service workers, and thus ok for WebAPKs, but it seems that for WebAPKs to be created https is required.  Let me know if I have something wrong with this thought process.

Comment: Definitely needs to be HTTPS. If you do an A2HS for a regular site it will add the chrome logo. You ran lighthouse with a non HTTPS (not localhost) URL and it passed all? That's odd.

Comment: You need to register a service worker for A2HS to kick in automatically I believe. If it's adding with the chrome symbol I don't think it's actually being installed to the device as a PWA

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I ended up not implementing a PWA into the application I was working on, so I guess I don't have a solution.  I will have to play around with PWAs in my next project to see if anything has changed.